# Error while declaring and initializing variable of the struct type

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, initialization, declaration

I have problem while creating the variable of Employee(struct) user defined type.Error says that member of struct type is not allowed like that.

```
struct Employee{

    char name[100];
    char address[100];

}emp[3];
int main(){

    char ch;
    int i=-1;
    fstream in;

    in.open("Muhammad.txt",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    do{
        i++;
        cout<<"\nEnter name:";cin.getline(emp.name[i],100);//error line
    cout<<"\nEnter address:";cin.getline(emp.address[i],100);//error line

        in.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp[i]),sizeof(Employee));         


    }while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

expected that object of Employee will be created normally

but got following error:
[Error] request for member 'name' in 'emp', which is of non-class type 'Employee [3]'

Comment: Pop quiz: 1) What is "`emp.name[i]`", what's its type?  2) What is the type of the first parameter to `std::getline`?

Comment: __C__ `!=` __C++__ `!=` __C#__, They are different languages and demand to be treaed as such. :) Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Choose one and stick to that please.

Comment: Just guessing, did you mean `emp[i].name` instead?

Comment: @StackDanny say, what?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
emp.name[i] has type char

Comment: @SouravGhosh
yes sorry for all above

Comment: @StackDanny whoppsie....

Comment: @SouravGhosh
yes sorry for all above

Answer (score 4):

You declared an array of three elements of the type `struct Employee`.

This construction

```
struct Employee{

    char name[100];
    char address[100];

}emp[3];
```

is equivalent to

```
struct Employee{

    char name[100];
    char address[100];

};

Employee emp[3];
```

And each element of the array has only one data member `name` and `address`.

So you have to write for example

```
getline(emp[i].name,100)
```

And the loop shall have no more than three iterations.

Moreover the variable `ch` was not initialized and is not changed in the loop.